# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: ataObject.PayMaster.PayTransactionStatement in dataObject.PayTransactionStatement.payMaster

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I getting below error

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: my.backend.dataObject.PayMaster.PayTransactionStatement in my.backend.dataObject.PayTransactionStatement.payMaster.

I checked all the entity but still can't solve the problem

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pay_master")
@DynamicUpdate //Dynamic update - you need to set the update time field of the database to be automatically updated. In this way, query the time, save the other fields and save the update time.
public class PayMaster {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="paymaster_id")
    private Long paymasterid;


    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="statement_id")
    private PayTransactionStatement payTransactionStatement;

}



@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pay_transaction_statement")
@DynamicUpdate
public class PayTransactionStatement {


     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name="statement_id")
     private Long statementId;

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy ="PayTransactionStatement") 
     private List<PayMaster> payMaster;

}
```

Comment: as @Tijkijiki pointed out rightfully, you need to start with a lowercase letter in your mapped by. This is due to spring boot naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping in `PayTransactionStatement` should be

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy ="payTransactionStatement") 
 private List<PayMaster> payMaster;
```